# SVG при наведении, добавленная фоном через css

Tags: css, svg

Вопрос такой, я сделал svg иконку с изменением цвета при наведении, я решил проблему сделав копию svg и заменив в самой svg цвет на который мне нужен, то есть я добавил два одинаковых класса с разными иконками-svg. И вот сам вопрос могу ли я каким-то образом сделать это компактнее, чтобы менялась при наведении та же иконка, которую я добавил в первый раз? А не добавлять копию иконки с другим цветом...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый простой способ вставить код картинки внутри HTML после чего можно будет манипулировать с помощью CSS.
Например:

```css
a svg {
  fill: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
    
a svg:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 477.175 477.175">
    <path d="M360.731 229.075l-225.1-225.1c-5.3-5.3-13.8-5.3-19.1 0s-5.3 13.8 0 19.1l215.5 215.5-215.5 215.5c-5.3 5.3-5.3 13.8 0 19.1 2.6 2.6 6.1 4 9.5 4 3.4 0 6.9-1.3 9.5-4l225.1-225.1c5.3-5.2 5.3-13.8.1-19z"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: А если сам код svg очень большой, если быть точным 145 строк, возможно ли просто подключить в html документ? как шрифт например(если такое возможно конечно). Но за способ спасибо!

Comment: Можно но подход не назовёшь чистым (правильным).

Comment: Например можно использовать filter вот генератор https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

Comment: То есть вы вставляете img src ну или background и потом уже hover и фильтром

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и способ, очень вам благодарен!!!